# daily stock market charts using java and svg

Tags: java, svg, charts

I want to know the more apt open source technology to plot the daily stock market data as a chart. Is this possible using java and svg? Where should I start from?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible. There are plenty of libraries for doing this sort of thing though.

For example in a website you can use Google charts:

https://developers.google.com/chart/

In a Java swing gui there are options like jfreechart:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

For SVG I imagine there are libraries for that as well, although it's not something I've tried myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Google charts seems to satisfy most of my requirements. I have to drill deeper to see Google Charts features.

Comment: Cool. Accept the answer if you happy with it. :)